# Nesting projects with shared resources in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, project

I have a custom web application project, where `project` and `webapp` are Eclipse projects. Assume a structure like the following

```
/project
    /webapp
        /_src
            /com.webapp.servlets
            /com.webapp.domain
            /com.webapp.services
```

Now I want to create java command line based tool to simulate the operations of a servlet. It's going to require classes from my `domain` package. I also need to split this command line application from the web application project. I would also need to extract those shared classes into another project as well.

I would like to have this type of structure

```
    /project
        /webapp
            /_src
                /com.webapp.servlets                 
                /com.webapp.services
        /commandline
             /_src
                 /com.commandline.simulation
        /shared
             /_src
                /com.webapp.domain
```

How can I achieve this nested project structure with shared resources in Eclipse (Indigo)?

Comment: I simply use multiple Source Folders in one Eclipse project, and it works great.

Comment: My problem is that I need to deploy each project in a separate jar, different build system.

Comment: If you build your jars with ant (an automated build system with eclipse plugin), you can create a different build target for every jar you need. If you don't already use Ant, it is well worth looking at and very versatile. It especially shines in situations like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was pretty simple. Create a new folder in your root project project. Then Create a Java Project but don't use default location, use the new folder you created. This will create a new entry in your project explorer, but on the file system you will have nested projects.

In projects that require resources from other projects just configure the build path by adding the projects you need,

Comment: Can you clarify what "just configure the build path by adding the projects you need" means?

Comment: @Kepboy If you right-click a project, select Build Path and Configure Build Path..., under Projects tab, you can _add_ any other projects which are in your current workspace.